# skimage.transform.resize() to the original size

Tags: resize, scikit-image

```
a = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
skimage.transform.resize(a, (a.shape))
```

returns

```
array([[6.98491931e-10, 6.98491931e-10],
       [6.98491931e-10, 6.98491931e-10]])
```

I was expecting the output to be the same with the original matrix since I am not shrinking the size. Is it padding the matrix with zeros?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**. Though not the best solution, you can go around this "problem" by using preserve_range=True.

```
skimage.transform.resize(a, a.shape, preserve_range=True)
```

**Long answer**. skimage needs to convert your image to float before resizing it because of all the interpolation math that will take place. Now, the method used on this conversion will depend on the data type of your array. In your example, it is probably an int32 (if I run your code on my machine I get int64). Therefore, the maximum value is 2^31-1. And the matrix that you got out of the resize fuction is something around 1/(2^31-1). The conversion is therefore correct. So, what is the best way to solve your problem?

**Best solution** Create an array using a skimage supported data type, resize it, and (if necessary) bring it back to the original data type.

```
a = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]], dtype=np.uint8)
b = skimage.transform.resize(a, a.shape)
c = skimage.img_as_ubyte(b)

>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
>>> b
array([[0.00392157, 0.00392157],
       [0.00392157, 0.00392157]])
>>> c
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```